# Normalize JSON format in python with groupby

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a list of JSONs that I need to groupby the 'day' field and format. Here is an example of the the data and what the final output should look like.

```
data = [{'info': {'area': 'USA', 'other': 'cat'}, 'day': '1-1-2012', 'num': 12},
    {'info': {'area': 'KSA', 'other': 'bat'}, 'day': '1-1-2012', 'num': 52},
    {'info': {'area': 'KSA', 'other': 'fat'}, 'day': '4-3-2012', 'num': 34},]
```

The desired output should be:

```
[{'1-1-2012': {'area' : {'USA', 'KSA'}, 'num': {12, 52}}, '4-3-2012': {'area': {'KSA'}, 'num': {34}}}]
```

I tried using pd.json_normmalize() to make the entire list into a dataframe first but I believe there is an easier way to achieve the above output.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you not care about the `other` field?

Comment: It's unclear what your data transformation looks like. Do you not care which `num`s are associated with which `info`s? Also: per the above comment, what happened to `info.other`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you start with a dataframe created from `data`, you can extract the area values, `groupby` the day and then convert back to JSON:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
out = (df
      .assign(area=df['info'].apply(lambda d:d['area']))
      .drop('info',axis=1)
      .groupby('day')
      .agg(list)
      .to_json(orient='index')
      )
```

Output for your sample data:

```
'{"1-1-2012":{"num":[12,52],"area":["USA","KSA"]},"4-3-2012":{"num":[34],"area":["KSA"]}}'
```

Note that if your actual desired output is a dictionary with sets for values, you can change the aggregation to `set` and replace the call to `to_json` with `to_dict`:

```
out = (df
      .assign(area=df['info'].apply(lambda d:d['area']))
      .drop('info',axis=1)
      .groupby('day')
      .agg(set)
      .to_dict(orient='index')
      )
```

Output:

```
{
  '1-1-2012': {
    'num': {12, 52},
    'area': {'USA', 'KSA'}
  },
  '4-3-2012': {
    'num': {34},
    'area': {'KSA'}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your desired data structure is probably wrong in some fundamental way, but assuming for the sake of argument that this lossy transformation *is* what you want, you could do:

```py
data = [{'info': {'area': 'USA', 'other': 'cat'}, 'day': '1-1-2012', 'num': 12},
    {'info': {'area': 'KSA', 'other': 'bat'}, 'day': '1-1-2012', 'num': 52},
    {'info': {'area': 'KSA', 'other': 'fat'}, 'day': '4-3-2012', 'num': 34},]

result = {}

for d in data:
    day = d['day']
    row = result.setdefault(day, {'area': set(), 'num': set()})
    row['area'].add(d['info']['area'])
    row['num'].add(d['num'])
```

which gives:

```
>>> result
{'1-1-2012': {'area': {'USA', 'KSA'}, 'num': {12, 52}}, '4-3-2012': {'area': {'KSA'}, 'num': {34}}}
```