# Json formatting with a groupby

Tags: python, dictionary

This is follow up from [Normalize JSON format in python with groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77177087/normalize-json-format-in-python-with-groupby) this question. I would like the output to be a list of dictionaries in the following format. Essentially, I am grouping by the day field and storing the associated values in a list. Kinda new to JSON so I appreciate the help.

Thanks!

sample data:

```
data = [{'info': {'area': 'USA', 'other': 'cat'}, 'day': '1-1-2012', 'num': 12},
{'info': {'area': 'KSA', 'other': 'bat'}, 'day': '1-1-2012', 'num': 52},
{'info': {'area': 'KSA', 'other': 'fat'}, 'day': '4-3-2012', 'num': 34}]
```

desired output:

```
out = [{'day': '1-1-2012', 'area': ['USA', 'KSA'], 'num': [12, 52]}, {'day': '4-3-2012', 'area': 'KSA', 'num': 34}]
```

Comment: Please show what you tried.

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON, which is a string representation of data. This is just about lists and dictionaries.

Comment: The general solution to grouping data is to use a dictionary whose keys are the field you want to group by.

Comment: You junt need group by the key "day"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Normalize JSON format in python with groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77177087/normalize-json-format-in-python-with-groupby)

Answer (score 0):

Since It looks like you only care about `day`, `area`, and `num`, your first step would be extracting those values.

```
data = [
    {
        "area": x["info"]["area"],  # Extract `area`
        **{k:v for k,v in x.items() if k != 'info'},  # Drop `info`
    } 
    for x in data
]
```

`data` now looks like:

```
[{'area': 'USA', 'day': '1-1-2012', 'num': 12},
 {'area': 'KSA', 'day': '1-1-2012', 'num': 52},
 {'area': 'KSA', 'day': '4-3-2012', 'num': 34}]
```

Now, you've shown a lack of code, which appears as no visible effort made on your part. We're not here to do your work for you.

#### ***Show us what you have tried so far, explain exactly where you've gotten stuck.***

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
data = [
    {"info": {"area": "USA", "other": "cat"}, "day": "1-1-2012", "num": 12},
    {"info": {"area": "KSA", "other": "bat"}, "day": "1-1-2012", "num": 52},
    {"info": {"area": "KSA", "other": "fat"}, "day": "4-3-2012", "num": 34},
]


out = {}
for d in data:
    out.setdefault(d["day"], []).append(d)

out = [
    {"day": k, "area": [d["info"]["area"] for d in v], "num": [d["num"] for d in v]}
    for k, v in out.items()
]

# change one-item lists to values:
out = [
    {
        "day": d["day"],
        "area": d["area"].pop() if len(d["area"]) == 1 else d["area"],
        "num": d["num"].pop() if len(d["num"]) == 1 else d["num"],
    }
    for d in out
]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[
    {"day": "1-1-2012", "area": ["USA", "KSA"], "num": [12, 52]},
    {"day": "4-3-2012", "area": "KSA", "num": 34},
]
```